# Common collector amplifier gives much less voltage than expected?

Tags: current, amplifier, circuit-design, common-collector

Common collector amplifier gives a good current gain and there is a link on internet, that makes the calculation for current amplification automatically.

http://www.vk2zay.net/calculators/transistors/commonCollector.php

I tested it in LTSpice. I placed the components into circuit with given inputs. Unfortunately, it seems to be working
wrong somehow, because the expected output voltage should be at the value nearly the input voltage, but it is much less than the input. I did something wrong. Could you help me to build and place the needed components into the common collector amplifier?

Why is not the circuit below working from LTSpice? Why does it give much less voltage than expected? How can I correct this?

[image: circuit]

Edit:

Below a working example. It works as expected.

```
frequency 3.3 MHz
Input voltage: 1V
Output voltage : ~1V
```

It has a current gain about 20.

[image: working]

Comment: 110k bias for 10ohm load force too low current to base.

Comment: Also output cap is too small for driving 10ohms at 1khz.

Comment: Also Rser is too high for such low output impedance. You would need a two stages.

Comment: What voltage input and output are you measuring? With that design you will not be able to get more than about 3mV RMS output.

Comment: @KevinWhite Hi. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as described in the table above the voltage gain should be around 0.27. I had neglected this value and was normal for the desired result with the given input values.

Answer (score 2):

There are two effects in play here, both are related to the quiescent current in Q1.

With the bias resistor values being used there is only about 1mA quiescent current flowing through R3. That will mean that the effective output resistance is going to be about 25 ohms (25/Ie - the simulation shows it as being 29 ohms) Since your load is only 10 ohms the gain will be about 10/(10 + 25) = 0.28.

A second problem is that it will be easily overloaded with a maximum output of only a few millivolts.  The maximum current that can be sent to the load is the change between the transistor being cutoff (ie zero current) and twice the quiescent current when the signal goes positive.

In this case it would be 2mA peak to peak.

2mA into the 10 ohm load only results in 20mV peak to peak or about 6mV RMS.

The quiescent current through the transistor needs to be greatly increased by reducing the value of R1. For example changing R1 to 10k would result in about 6V across R3 giving about 30mA quiescent current. This would reduce the output resistance to a couple of ohms, improving the gain, and increase the maximum output level.

With 30mA through R3 the load current could increase to 60mA pk-pk giving 600mV pk-pk or about 200mV RMS output.